# javascript post data to new window

Tags: javascript, http-post

I would like to post two strings to a new php webpage ( which will open as a new window ) which I can then extract using `$_POST`.

Can anyone point me in the direction of Javascript code which can open the new window and post the data?

( I want to use JS to create the post as the strings will be complex and generated at runtime based on arrays I have already).

Just as a simple example could anyone show me how i would post two strings via a JS function.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the parent page, make sure you have the form. 
Then with JavaScript, open a new window and make sure you have a handle to it
Then have that same JavaScript post the form on the parent page to the new window you opened
Finally you will have access to your data via $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Window.open returns a reference to the new window. With that you have access to the new window's global namespace.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open